# Bypass or edit javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

Before anyone makes any assumptions, I am trying to bypass the forced timers on a course which is required to renew one of my certs. Frustratingly, the course is seemingly identical to the original and has me reading things I have already read before. Truly I wish I could skip it and just take the quizzes, which is where I need some help.

I have already tried to make sense of some of the other similar questions, but alas, I am no programmer.

Anyways, here is the bit of code that I *think* needs looked at, but hopefully someone can direct me as to if I need to provide something different.

```
<div class="t-col option-next">
    <span id="PlaybuttonEn" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:;" title="Next" class="btn ctrl"><span id="PlaybuttonEnText">NEXT</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i>
    </a>
    </span>
    <span id="PlaybuttonDs" style="display: inline;">
        <div id="scene-duration" class="timer-bar slideIn">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 48.5714%;"></div>
            </div>
            <label><span id="timer" title="Button is enabled" style="display: inline;">00:17</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:;" title="" class="btn ctrl enabled" enabled="enabled"><span id="PlaybuttonDsText" title="ok">NEXT</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Any help would be super appreciated. This has been a thorn in my side for a few hours now.

Comment: Could you clarify the question?  Do you need to go to the next page without waiting for the timer to count down to 0?  Also, what browser are you using?  What happens if you simply disable javascript?

Comment: Also, maybe include a screen shot (you can upload to imgur) to get a better idea of what you're trying to do/bypass.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I need to  get to the next page without waiting on the timer. I'm currently in Chrome. Disabling javascript keeps the page from loading, it seems.

@DanChrostowski not sure how comments work on here yet.

Comment: Can you right click on the link that is disabled in chrome, choose Inspect, then in the resulting developer pane choose the Event Listeners tab located toward the bottom, then look for the click event as shown here:
http://imgur.com/a/vU7ZA

Comment: And after you get that, click on the whatever_file.js link on the right hand side and paste the function which handles the click.  Or better yet, if this is publicly accessible without a password just send the link.

Comment: Or try this as a stab in the dark - right click on the NEXT link, choose Inspect, and double click on the `<a href="javascript:;"...` element and modify `"enabled"` to `"disabled"`.  No guarantees, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @DanChrostowski This is what I've got: http://imgur.com/a/pWDIV 

The contents of those were quite large and I'm not sure how to copy them.

Haha oops, yeah that was what I already tried, and it didn't work. I guess I forgot to change it back.

Comment: instead of the `<span>`, get the `<a>` element loaded into the developer console.  It's a few lines down in your screen shot.  There should be a click event handler on that.  Once I can see what the javascript code is doing, then I can figure out if it's possible to bypass.  There aren't any guarantees though, for example it may be making a backend call to the server which could be double checking the timer.  In which case the only way to go to the next link is to wait.

Comment: @DanChrostowski

To my eyes, it looks pretty much the same. I clicked a few of the arrows if that helps at all: http://imgur.com/a/92zbK

Comment: Can you expand Global and Closure?

Comment: @DanChrostowski

Is there a way to copy it all? It's extremely long and each one has another tree as long as the one before it.

Comment: @DanChrostowski

This may be helpful? I inspected the "NEXT" button when it was "clickable" and that new "a.btn.ctrl" item popped up. It's not there when the NEXT button is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the timer is being controlled by either a `setInterval` or a `setTimeout` function.
If that is the case, for chrome, you can do `Ctrl + Shift + I` to open your chrome  dev tools. From there, navigate to your console and paste in:

```
// The multiple factor to speed up the intervals by
const speedup = 10;

// Create a backup of the set timeout function
const originalTime = window.setTimeout;

// Override the original set timout function
setTimeout = function(callback, millis) {
  // Run the original function but with a modified delay
  return originalTime(callback, millis/speedup);
}

// Do the same thing with the set interval function
const originalInt = window.setInterval;
setInterval = function(callback, millis) {
  return originalInt(callback, millis/speedup);
}
```

Then do `Ctrl + R` to reload the page then quickly click `Enter` to run the code snippet before the page loads, overriding the intervals!

Answer (score -1):

mate you forgot the / before "div" in a bunch of lines it should be `</div>` same with "span" and everything else it should have </"whatever you are doing">

here is the slightly fixed code:

```
</div class="t-col option-next">
</span id="PlaybuttonEn" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:;" title="Next" class="btn ctrl"><span id="PlaybuttonEnText">NEXT<span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i>
</a>
</span>
</span id="PlaybuttonDs" style="display: inline;">
    </div id="scene-duration" class="timer-bar slideIn">
        </div class="progress">
            </div class="progress-bar" style="width: 48.5714%;"><div>
        </div>
        </label><span id="timer" title="Button is enabled" style="display: inline;">00:17<span>
        </label>
    </div>
    </a href="javascript:;" title="" class="btn ctrl enabled" enabled="enabled"><span id="PlaybuttonDsText" title="ok">NEXT<span></i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i><a>
</span>
```

Comment: this code was provided by the app, not the questioner

Comment: That is not how HTML works